# Cucumber API for listing/run features/scenarios/tags

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Are there some API (for Java lang) which can be used to:

1. Retrieve the list of features files and all their scenarios
2. Retrieve list of tags
3. With information from 1 and 2, run a subset of these feature/scenarios either by name or by tag.

I intend to wrap these APIs with rest endpoints.

**Later edit**

pom.xml content

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.16.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cucumber in combination with the [JUnit (5) Platform Engine](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine), you can use the [JUnit Launcher API](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api) to programmatically do all those things.

For example listing scenarios and their tags:

```java
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants;
import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;

public class LauncherDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();


    // Listing
    TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(
        LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .configurationParameter(Constants.JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, "long")
            .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage("io.cucumber.skeleton"))
            .build()
    );
    
    testPlan.getRoots().stream()
        .flatMap(root -> testPlan.getDescendants(root).stream())
        .filter(TestIdentifier::isTest)
        .forEach(testIdentifier -> {
          System.out.println(testIdentifier.getDisplayName() + " " + testIdentifier.getTags());
        });


    // Execution
    SummaryGeneratingListener summary = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(summary);

    launcher.execute(
        LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .configurationParameter(Constants.JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, "long")
            .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage("io.cucumber.skeleton"))
            .filters(TagFilter.includeTags("ExampleTag"))
            .build()
    );

    summary.getSummary().printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));


  }
}
```

Comment: the code is compiling but I cannot find any test. do you have an working example of how to configure the launcher in respect to the folder/package structure?

Comment: Are you on the latest spring boot?

Comment: And when using `selectPackage("io.cucumber.skeleton")` you features should be in `src/main/resources/io/cucumber/skeleton`. The main part is important because tests are not included in a spring boot executable jar, same for your step definitions.

Comment: I don't have a working example on hand but the reproducer from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2828 should be just that if you upgrade the cucumber version.