# Only run some cucumber tests in parallel and run the rest sequentially using gradle tasks

Tags: kotlin, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, parallel-testing

I have some cucumber tests that can be run in in parallel, and some that can't. I want a way to run them all at once. The only way I can think of doing it is to run the parallel tests first and then run the rest of the tests sequentially and merge the test report somehow.
I have a test framework that uses Kotlin, Cucumber and Gradle. I currently have a gradle task that reads in the tags as system properties, and based on the tags it sets the number of threads to use to run the cucumber task. I know there is a limitation on gradle vs maven for running in parallel, but maven isn't really an option for me.

This is basic gradle task that runs cucumber, using a different number of threads based on the `@parallel` tag being passed in:

```
task("cucumber") {
    dependsOn("assemble", "compileTestJava")
    var tags: String = getProperty("tags", "((@api) and (not @skip) and (not @bug)")
    var threads: String = "1"
    if(tags.contains("@parallel")) {
        threads = "4"
    }
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            mainClass.set("io.cucumber.core.cli.Main")
            classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
            systemProperties(System.getProperties().mapKeys { it.key as String })
            args = listOf(
                "--plugin", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm",
                "--glue", "com.myproject", "src/test/resources",
                "--tags", tags,
                "--threads", threads
            )
            environment("tags", tags)
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to chain 2 commands in gradle, one immediately after the other? I tried the following and there was about a 2 min delay in between one cucumber run finishing, and the other one starting:

```
fun runCucumber() {
    var tags = ""
    var threads = ""
    javaexec {
        mainClass.set("io.cucumber.core.cli.Main")
        classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
        systemProperties(System.getProperties().mapKeys { it.key as String })
        tags = getProperty("tags", "((@api) and (not @skip) and (not @bug)")
        threads = getProperty("threads", "1")
        if (tags.contains("@parallel")) {
            threads = "4"
        }
        args = listOf(
            "--plugin", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm",
            "--glue", "com.myproject", "src/test/resources",
            "--tags", tags,
            "--threads", threads
        )
        environment("tags", tags)
    }
    exec {
        if (tags.contains("@parallel")) {
            javaexec {
                mainClass.set("io.cucumber.core.cli.Main")
                classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
                systemProperties(System.getProperties().mapKeys { it.key as String })
                tags = getProperty("tags", "(@api) and (not @parallel)")
                threads = getProperty("threads", "1")
                args = listOf(
                    "--plugin", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm",
                    "--glue", "com.myproject", "src/test/resources",
                    "--tags", tags,
                    "--threads", threads
                )
                environment("tags", tags)
            }
        }
    }
}

task("cucumber") {
    dependsOn("assemble", "compileTestJava")
    doLast {
        runCucumber()
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve what I'm asking for using gradle tasks?

It also brings up the question of whether there is a better/different way to achieve what I need, without using multiple gradle tasks or commands?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Gradle provides the [Worker API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/worker_api.html) for breaking a task up into parts that can be executed in parallel.

Comment: You could also write your own main method that runs the main method from Cucumber twice. Or if you use the Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine you can also use JUnits 5 Launcher API which is more flexible than Cucumbers CLI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78224797/3945473